# Unexpect Token Error in HQL Query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm having an issue with the following code meant to pull a unique object from a database using HQL.

```
public class VipFeeStructureFacade {
    private static String QUERY_BASED_ON_DISPLAY_NAME ="from VipFeeStructure v where v.displayName = ";

    private String createQueryOnDisplayName(String displayName) {
        String query = "";

        query = displayName;

        return QUERY_BASED_ON_DISPLAY_NAME + query;
    }

    public VipFeeStructure getVipFeeStructureFromDisplayName(String displayName) {
        return (VipFeeStructure)FacadeTools.executeHQLQueryForUniqueObject(createQueryOnDisplayName(displayName));
    }
}
```

The SQL code that returns the same information is:

```
select * from Vip_Fee_Structure v where v.display_name = "..."
```

and this runs fine, but running `getVipFeeStructureFromDisplayName()` returns the following error:

```
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
    ERROR: line 1:68: unexpected token: m
    Feb 13, 2015 10:29:30 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:68: unexpected token: m
line 1:68: unexpected token: m
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.concatenation(HqlBaseParser.java:668)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.relationalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2721)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.equalityExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2677)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.negatedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2546)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalAndExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2462)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalOrExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2427)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.expression(HqlBaseParser.java:2137)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:1913)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.whereClause(HqlBaseParser.java:474)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:729)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:316)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:179)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:295)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1800)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor419.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:356)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.createQuery(Unknown Source)
```

Any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should enclose the "parameter" in single quotes.

If, for example, `displayName` is `myName`, the query will look like `where v.displayName = myName`, when instead it should be `where v.displayName = 'myName'`.

Anyway, you should be using real parameters instead of string concatenation.